# WP7 Mango how to update particular secondary Tile

Tags: windows-phone-7, push-notification, windows-phone-7.1, tiles, mpns

In our Mango app, We are providing the option to the user to pin many items to the start screen as secondary tiles. If we need to update only particular secondary tile among many tiles through push notification, what do we need to do.

Also How to delete a particular secondary tile when there are many secondary tiles in the start screen.

Comment: Although there is an API to remove tiles you should not do this in code! The users start screen is theirs you shouldn't change it for the user. Let the user delete tiles themselves that they no longer wish to keep.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This tutorial is showing you how to update secondary tiles with push notifications. http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Get-to-Mango-7-Using-Push-39228be6

As you can see in this example the URL is used to identify a (secondary) tile.